# OpenCV mingw-make32 Makefile:12: *** multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, mingw

I installed mingw gcc, g++ compiler. I downloaded the opencv source for 2.4.10. Then I used the following commands to compile the source:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mingw32-g++.exe -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make.exe ..

mingw32-make

mingw32-make install
```

Then I added the lib to my windows PATH. I use the following Makefile to compile the code but I get an error(using windows cmd):

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

SRCS = main.cpp input_main.cpp image_manuplation.cpp track_object.cpp
PROG = main.exe

OPENCV = -I"C:\Users\Username\Documents\opencv\sources\release\install\include" -I. -L"C:\Users\Username\Documents\opencv\sources\release\install\x86\mingw\lib" -lopencv_calib3d2410 -lopencv_contrib2410 -lopencv_core2410 -lopencv_features2d2410 --lopencv_flann2410 -lopencv_gpu2410 -lopencv_highgui2410 -lopencv_imgproc2410 -lopencv_legacy2410 -lopencv_ml2410 -lopepncv_nonfree2410 -lopencv_objdetect2410 -lopencv_ocl2410 -lopencv_photo2410 -lopencv_stitching2410 -lopencv_superres2410 -lopencv_ts2410 -lopencv_video2410 -lopencv_videostab2410

all : $(PROG)

$(PROG) : $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(SRCS) $(OPENCV)

clean:
    @del $(PROG)
```

I get the following error:

```
Makefile:12: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

Would someone know how to fix the error? I did similar thing on Ubuntu and it works.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a tab at the start of the `$(CC) $(CFLAGS)` or some number of spaces? I'm betting you have a tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 12 is the recipe line.  I believe you haven't started that line with a TAB character.  Make requires a real TAB, not just spaces.  Make sure your editor is capable of inserting a TAB character and doesn't "helpfully" convert it to spaces for you when you save.

Comment: Hi MadScientist, Thank you for the answer. I was too tired and forgot that I have set my vim to insert spaces everywhere I add a tab.